# How can I hide and element using CSS on initial page load until the Javascript link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I currently have a webpage that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to make it so the "Click to view Gallery of This property" button does not show on the initial load, but does show once the property links are clicked.

Here is an example of my current code:

```
    function changeImage(image, link) {
    document.getElementById('imageReplace').src = image;
    document.getElementById('linkReplace').href = link;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#/" onclick="changeImage('IMAGE', 'LINK');  return false">TEXT</a>
<a href="#/" onclick="changeImage('IMAGE', 'LINK');  return false">TEXT</a>
<a href="#/" onclick="changeImage('IMAGE', 'LINK');  return false">TEXT</a>

<img src="INITALPAGELOADIMAGE" alt="Images" id="imageReplace" class="changeImageClass">

<a href="#" id="linkReplace"><span style="float: right; padding:2px;"><Button>Click to view Gallery of This Property</button></span></a>
```

From what I understand I will want to use to use this function to hide the element:

```
document.getElementById('element').style.display = 'none';
```

But I am unsure how to work this into my current code. Do I add this with my current function, or is this a separate function all together?

If someone could point me into the right direction of how to code this properly I would really appreciate it.

Thank you so much,
-Kasandra

Comment: Just put that line somewhere in a script that loads after the DOM is ready (or after that element in the document). Better, use actual CSS to avoid load flashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is one of those exceptional cases where you want to use inline style to hide your element. This is because it takes a few seconds for the JavaScript to load. So some users may end up seeing the element when they first get on the page, then see it quickly disappear.

```
<img src="INITALPAGELOADIMAGE" alt="Images" id="imageReplace" class="changeImageClass" style="display: none;">
<a href="#" id="linkReplace" style="display: none"><span style="float: right; padding:2px;"><Button>Click to view Gallery of This Property</button></span></a>
```

Add an `onclick` attribute to your property links,

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeImage('IMAGE', 'LINK'); return false;">TEXT</a>
```

And use the following function to show the elements

```
function changeImage (src, href) {
    // get a reference to the DOM elements
    var img = document.getElementById('imageReplace'),
        link = document.getElementById('linkReplace');
    // update the elements
    img.src = src;
    link.href = href;
    // show the elements
    img.style.display = '';
    link.style.display = '';
}
```

Here's a quick [demo (updated)](https://jsbin.com/xaluqufina/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: The inline style removes the items visibility completely. Even when clicking on the links beside it after the page loads nothing shows.

Comment: I have updated my answer on how to show the hidden elements after clicking on another element. If your other element is a link, you will need to make sure `href` is `#` or else it will do its default behavior and go to another page.

Comment: currently right now my property links already have an onclick action. This is what my link code looks like now: <a href="#/" onclick="changeImage('IMAGE', 'LINK');show()">TEXT</a>
My Javascript looks like this: function changeImage(image, link) {
 document.getElementById('imageReplace').src = image;
 document.getElementById('linkReplace').href = link;
}

function show () {
    document.getElementById('imageReplace').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('linkReplace').style.display = '';
}
The function is still not working properly.

Comment: Merge the two functions together. Look at my updated answer again. The demo shows it working.

Answer (score 0):

Using css, you can have the block have `display: none;` and then when you use show it will change the display to default (usually `display: block;`)